# Eclipse RCP, adding a new View to Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

How is it possible to put a View into an Editor. Something like:

```
public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {
public static final String ID = "com.example.gui.perspective";
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(true);
    String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea(); 
    layout.addView(View.ID, IPageLayout.TOP, 0.6f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);    
... 
}
```

But there are only IPageLayout.TOP, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, IPageLayout.LEFT and IPageLayout.RIGHT options. I want to put it inside. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. Eclipse clearly distinguishes the *editor area*, which contains only *editors*, from all other areas, which contain only *views*.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I have created a new class, which extends EditorPart. But I am still struggling how to add the editor to my app.

Answer (score 0):

You tell Eclipse about an editor using the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
        name="Sample Multi-page Editor"
        extensions="mpe"
        icon="icons/sample.gif"
        contributorClass="tested.editors.MultiPageEditorContributor"
        class="tested.editors.MultiPageEditor"
        id="tested.editors.MultiPageEditor">
  </editor>
</extension>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already have this extension in plugins.xml, nothing is being shown.

Comment: It won't show up until you Open a file of the appropriate type. Editors do not open until they are needed.

Comment: Thank you, done. Where I can get IEditor input (I dont want to create anything - I need to just display my View in place where editor is)?

Comment: As already stated you can't, only editors can appear in the editor area.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. You can add a view in a **perspective** when you initialize the perspective.

However, I think it's possible to notify the perspective to add a view when you initialize the editor.